# Jersey server, rest api : How to remove the code and type from the response body?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, swagger

I'm trying to create a Rest Api using Jax-rs Jersey from a base code generated by swagger.

The specifications are for exemple for a specific Request :
Code : 200
Description : User token for login
Schema : String

My problem is that the generated code use the class :javax.ws.rs.core.Response that should not be extended according to the documentation.

I'm using this kind of code to build the response :

```
return Response.ok().entity(new ApiResponseMessage(ApiResponseMessage.OK,apiToken)).build();
```

The response generated looks like that :

```
{"code":4,"type":"ok","message":"uHN2cE7REfZz1pD17ITa"}
```

When i only want to have :"uHN2cE7REfZz1pD17ITa" in the body. Is that possible using Jersey ? Or is this format part of the jax-rs specifications ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ApiResponseMessage` from Swagger does not extend `Response` from JAX-RS. Check the [code](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/samples/server/petstore/jaxrs/jersey2/src/gen/java/io/swagger/api/ApiResponseMessage.java) and you will see that `ApiResponseMessage` is just a POJO. That is, the piece of code you posted in your question is just fine.

If you only need the token, you can use:

```java
return Response.ok(apiToken).build();
```

The following gives you the same result:

```java
return Response.ok().entity(apiToken).build();
```

Since your resource method will produce just a piece of text (not a valid JSON unless the piece of text is wrapped into quotes), the most suitable media type for the response would be `text/plain`. It could be achieved by either annotating the resource method with `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)` or setting the media type in the response, as following:

```java
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response getToken() {
    String apiToken = ...
    return Response.ok(apiToken).build();  
}
```

```java
@GET
public Response getToken() {
    String apiToken = ...
    return Response.ok(apiToken, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();  
}
```

Alternatively you also could make your method return just a `String`:

```java
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getToken() {
    String apiToken = ...
    return apiToken;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RS does not require Request or Response in specific format  for text,json, xml, or html fallowing a schema  . But They all have to be well formated in according to their specifications.

You can send text response like this in jersey
like this

```
return Response.ok().entity("uHN2cE7REfZz1pD17ITa").build();
```

I am new to swagger myself So i don't know if the Response in question can be changed or not . But There is no restriction from jersey side